# output routes and avoid the routes which user input in prolog

Tags: path, prolog

output prolog list path and avoid certain routes which user input in prolog.

hi ,I'm working on a project , a building contains zones , each zone has an exit , we want to evacuate people through the zones to exits ,the user input two parameters ,the first one is the "infected zone" ,the other parameter is "zone of people we want to evacuate".
the output should be all the safe routes from the "zone of people we want to evacuate" to exits avoiding the infected zone.

for example :
 user input `(z11, z12)`  // it means z11 is infected , people we want to evacuate is in z12.

output : `z12->z22->exit3. and 
z12->z21->exit2. and z12->elevators`

the facts are :

```
 path(z11,z12).
 path(z12,z11).
 path(z12,z22).
 path(z12,z21).
 path(z22,z12).
 path(z22,z21).
 path(z21,z22).
 path(z11,exit1).
 path(z12,elevators).
 path(z21,exit2).
 path(z22,exit3).
```

please help me writing the code.

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's inconvenient that you've chosen to name your predicate `path/2` since we'd probably want to call the thing that generates a path to the exit with that name. So first I'd rename all your facts from `path/2` to `connected/2`. Then you're going to want to annotate the exits:

```
exit(exit1). exit(exit2).
exit(elevators).
```

Otherwise you'd have to hard-code them somewhere else.

A simple thing to do would be to solve the general path question and then check to ensure the path doesn't contain an infected site. That would look like this:

```
path(Start, Path) :- path(Start, Path, []).

path(Start, [Exit], Seen) :-
    exit(Exit),
    connected(Start, Exit),
    \+ memberchk(Exit, Seen).
path(Start, [Next|Rest], Seen) :-
    connected(Start, Next),
    \+ memberchk(Next, Seen),
    path(Next, Rest, [Next|Seen]).

safe_path(Start, Avoid, Path) :-
    path(Start, Path),
    \+ memberchk(Avoid, Path).
```

This easily generalizes to handle sets of avoid zones:

```
safe_path(Start, AvoidList, Path) :-
    path(Start, Path),
    forall(member(Avoid, AvoidList), \+ memberchk(Avoid, Path)).
```

The bulk of what's interesting and fun to do in Prolog is accomplished with a generate/test paradigm. The simplest and most direct formulation is usually one in which you generate too much (too generally, you might say) and put all the restrictions in the test. Generally speaking, you achieve better performance by making the generator more intelligent about generating possibilities--moving code from the "test" part into the "generate" part of "generate and test."

Usually the first problem you face is generating an infinite tree. This is particularly true with graphs. The `memberchk/2` in `path/3` with the `Seen` list serves to prevent looping back and is necessary to make the set of paths finite. Using `exit/1` in the base case of `path/3` also helps performance because we're not generating intermediate paths. It's nice that with your particular situation you can get away with this.

Doing the avoidance at the end is winnowing out chaff last. The generation doesn't know to avoid these nodes so all of the poisoned paths will get generated and removed by the test. If performance isn't sufficient this way, you can move that code into `path/2` directly, doing a similar kind of check to the one done with the `Seen` list.

Comment: Thank You a lot , but can you please help me to solve this issue: the user should enter the two parameters using a GUI window >>> how could i code that by making user enter the two parameters ???

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to do some programming yourself. Use [XPCE](http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/xpce/).

Comment: hi , i want to ask after implementing the code for example if the start point is : z11 and the infected zone is :exit3 , the results are :  Q = [exit1] ; Q = [z12, elevators] ; Q = [z12, z11, exit1] ; Q = [z12, z21, exit2] ; false. then in the third path the people will go from z11 to z12 then go back again to z11 >>>>>this should not be happen >>>>how could i remove the third choice ????

Comment: also ,how could it produce a complete answer( the path output begins with the start point) for example : "the start point is" z11 , and the infected zone is "exit3" , the result should be [z11->z12->elevators] and [z11->exit1] ...etc.

Comment: Both of those problems have obvious solutions. Try.

Comment: ok ,the idea of the first problem is to make the path avoid passing through the start point , just give me a hint how to do that .^ـــ^

Comment: You need to get the value of `Start` into `Seen` so that the subsequent `\+ memberchk(...)` does the work for you.

Comment: i put this statement  \+ memberchk(Start, Seen), in the code,but the problem that the start value is changing according to recursion , how can i tell that the start value is the first element of the list ???

Comment: please help me finish this code ,its killing me :(

Comment: Both of the ills are corrected by redefining `path/2` like so: `path(Start, [Start|Path]) :- path(Start, Path, [Start])`. I strongly recommend you put some energy into the basics, because this really should not have been "killing you."

Comment: Thank you ,Thank you , I appreciate it .Yes i will learn prolog from the beginning , its just i was enforced  to do a simple implementation in a week , i was a little confused .

Comment: of course , its excellent and helpful for sure   ^ـــ^ .

Comment: Thanks. :) Do let me know if I can help more in the future.